# Is there a way to add tooltip to excel cell data in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am generating an excel sheet from multiple databases and wanted at particular column to add "Tooltip" to show, from where the data is being fetched.
All I want some property or method to set Tooltip of any excel cell.
At the moment I tried :

```
objCopy.Cells[j + Convert.ToInt16(StartRow["StartRow"]), 4].Tooltip = "From First Table";
```

And

```
objCopy.Cells[j + Convert.ToInt16(StartRow["StartRow"]), 4].setAttribute("title","From SpreadSheet");
```

Comment: Do you mean a `Comment` instead of `Tooltip`?  Excel does not have an object `Tooltip` for a `Range`.  If so, try [`Range.AddComment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.addcomment.aspx).

Comment: Do you want this "tooltip" to appear on mouseover or on mouseclick? You can use comments for mouseover, and data validation message on mouseclick. What library are you using for generating Excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Excel doesn't have tooltips. The only thing that comes close are comments.

The [`Range.AddComment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.addcomment.aspx) is what you need for that.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Can you please let me know how to use that. As of now I am using objCopy.Cells[j + Convert.ToInt16(StartRow["StartRow"]), 4].Range.AddComment("From SpreadSheet");
and it's still not working

Comment: I am getting  Error while invoking Range.

Comment: {System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Error while invoking Range.
   at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet]

Comment: Range is correct. I am just checking for some syntax stuff related to invoking range

Comment: Try to remove the `Range` in between.

Comment: yes The values are getting in properly and I am trying to put comment in the same loop

Comment: Removing it giving an exception. {"Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"} System.Exception {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}

Comment: does it apply to entire column . as it's coming when the comment line encountered for the second time.

Comment: It is a per cell setting. Not sure how many comments are allowed though. More than one at least.

Comment: I got what I was missing. Actually in may cases the data was overlapping which needs the comment to overlap too. And the error was when there is already comment inserted in a particular cell, it wasn't allowing me to insert one more like replacing it with new one. So the Solution is to clear previous Cell coment and add new one to it.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = objCopy.Cells[j + Convert.ToInt16(StartRow["StartRow"]), 4];
                                            range.ClearComments();
                                            range.AddComment("From Cogency");

Comment: Okay. Glad you found it.